I want to know how to distinguish the blocked test case?
When I execute a test case, I meet a blocked issue 'QP-12' in my test case list. So I can't test cases QP-13 - 17, because there are a series of test cases of 'QP-12'.
In this case, to share with QA & Dev-team - what do I call 'QP-12'?
For example, "Dear All, QP-12 is a xxxx issue so I can't continue to execute other test cases, it is a high priority issue, please check the issue!"

Blocked
Blocker
Blockage

In my opinion, No.1 is acceptable, No.2 is weird to call a test case, and No.3 is acceptable.
Please answer using words each own field.
Thank you for time to read.


Blocking issue


You can call it whatever you'd like / whatever makes sense in the context of your team.
If you're after the correct English, then a bug preventing you from executing a test case would be a blocker (not followed by the word 'issue'), or a blocking issue if you're detailing the issue itself.
So in your example, you'd say QP-12 is (or has) a blocker, so I can't continue... or QP-12 has a blocking issue, so I can't continue...
But really, as long as everyone knows what you're talking about, it's just semantics and doesn't really matter... I mean, we used to "block the beaver" when deploys were blocked. It doesn't make sense to anyone outside the company, but everyone in tech knew what it meant.

Thank you for explain!
"It doesn't make sense to anyone outside the company, but everyone in tech knew what it meant." is a point for me!
